# Symfony routing with params with specific structure

Tags: php, regex, symfony, routes

Is it possible to declare a route in symfony like this

```
/somestuff/{query}
```

Where the structure of the `query` would be

```
string-with-minus-id000001
```

I would like to be able to get the first part as an attribute in controller and the second part as id. Defining the route as

```
/somestuff/{name}-id{id}
```

did not work

Comment: why would you even do something like that???

Comment: client requirements of route

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameters-validation

Comment: You can of course use a regular expression to validate string-with-minus-id000001 but I don't think there is anything that will parse it for you.  Even the [parameter conversion](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) capability probably won't help.  You could probably use a request controller listener to do the parsing and inject the name and id into the request object.  And then something similar for generating url's.  I suppose the client always has to be right even when they are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it in annotation, here's the answer:

```
@Route(
   "/somestuff/{name}-id{id}",
   methods={"GET"} ,
   name="route_name",
   defaults={"name"=""},
   requirements={"name"=".*?", "id"="\d+"}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the structure would always look like this

```
/somestuff/{name}-id{id}
```

The universal way to get the **name** and **id** would be

```
/**
 * @Route("/somestuff/{slug}")
 */
public function someAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $reversed = strrev($slug);
    $paramArray = explode('-', $reversed, 1); // limit
    $id = strrev($paramArray[0]);
    $name = strrev($paramArray[1]);
    // rest of code
}
```